# VSCode is not picking up my python virtual environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a fresh virtual environment and VSCode project. My problem is that when I go to "Python: Select Interpreter", following the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-an-environment), the virtual environment is not one of the options.

My project folder structure looks like this:

```
parent
   |- bin
   |- include
   |- lib
```

The available interpreters in the dropdown are

```
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Comment: And your virtualenv is located where?
It should be inside of the project folder, not the project folder itself.

Comment: That is the answer to my question, thanks!

Comment: I have added the comment as answer, so that others can find the answer more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtualenv folder has to be inside of the project folder, not the project folder itself.